# Obj-c - Sorting arrays in dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of dictionaries (self.filteredData), and I'm trying to sort the dictionaries so that dictionaries in which a key contains value YES are placed at the top of my tableview:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ambassador"
                                                                     ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [self.filteredData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        NSLog(@"THE SORTED VERSION %@", sortedArray);


        NSString *first = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"first name"];
        NSString *last = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"last name"];
        NSString *area = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"neighbourhood"];
        NSString *city = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"city"];
```

This works, however I'm now unable to grab data from each array? This line:

```
 NSString *first = [sortedArray valueForKey:@"first name"];
```

Simply returns a bracket (.

That said, sortedArray is populated upon debugging, and returned in the correct sorted order (the data above is going into a table).

What should this line look like in order to correctly grab the array's data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a property on the array, not a specific index, try this:

```
[sortedArray[0] valueForKey:@"first name"];
```

Where `0` is the index you wish to access, in this case the first element.

Since this is going to be in a TableView you can access the elements based on their indexes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *name = [this.sortedArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"first name"];
    // render cell below
}
```

Comment: The sortedArray is going into a tableView, so I dont always only want to access the first element?

Comment: @Brittany you can use `indexPath.row` to get the corresponding index